# Skype 4.1.0.20 - pulseaudio is correctly set, but the microphone doesn't work

Tags: pulseaudio, skype, settings

I mentioned that my skype records during testcall the system intern sounds but not my voice.
In the Soundsettings i have no panel for configuration.

If I make a test with Sound Recorder, it works fine.
I can hear my voice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try to install pavucontrol.

```
sudo apt-get install pavucontrol
```

Then do the following:

1. Launch pavucontrol
  ```
  pavucontrol
  ```
2. The volume control window will open
3. Launch Skype
4. Call someone or call the Echo
5. Go back to the volume control window and click the Recording tab
6. Choose your microphone

Comment: Thank you very much.
This help me. ;)